# Foreach loop to modify variable

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and trying to set variable values inside a loop. Using these strings:

```
$Apple = 'Apple'
$Banana = 'Banana'
$Orange = 'Orange'
```

I'm trying to join the strings inside a loop:

```
$Fruits = @($Apple, $Banana, $Orange)
foreach ($Fruit in $Fruits)
{
    $Fruit = $Fruit + '.' + "Test"
    $Fruit
}
```

This works inside the scope of the loop. But how can I **set** the value of `$Apple, $Banana` and `$Orange` permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-6) and [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable?view=powershell-6). Bear in mind the array contains the variable **names**, not their **values**.

```
$Apple  = 'Apple'
$Banana = 'Banana'
$Orange = 'Orange'

$FruitVariables = @('Apple','Banana','Orange')

foreach ($Fruit in $FruitVariables)
{
    Set-Variable -Name $Fruit -Value ((Get-Variable -Name $Fruit).Value + ".Test")
}
```

---

If you're only interested in setting the values in the array, you could use index:

```
$Fruits = @($Apple, $Banana, $Orange)
foreach ($i in 0..($Fruits.Count - 1))
{
    $Fruits[$i] = $Fruits[$i] + '.' + "Test"
    $Fruits[$i]
}
```

---

I feel like there may be a more elegant solution using [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6), but the above is what's in the scope of my knowledge.